# i cant update one table to another table in oracle 11g

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

```
UPDATE STOCKVALUE A 
     SET A.LOCATION=(SELECT B.LOCID FROM DCCUMINVBASIC B WHERE A.MAPNAME='invdc4')
```

> Error:ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: The error message is clear: There are instances where the subquery is returning more than one record.  Hence, Oracle can't figure out _which_ `LOCID` value to use in the update for a given record in the `STOCKVALUE` table.

Comment: you are setting LOCATION which has to be 1 value. check your sub query it's returning more that 1 row ..  SELECT B.LOCID FROM DCCUMINVBASIC B WHERE A.MAPNAME='invdc4'

Comment: I given Stockvalue location ID too (A.MAPNAME='invdc4' and a.location=10155000000024)

Comment: UPDATE STOCKVALUE A SET A.LOCATION=(SELECT DISTINCT B.LOCID FROM STOCKVALUE A,DCCUMINVBASIC B WHERE A.DOCID=B.DOCID AND A.MAPNAME='invdc4'AND A.MPLANT IS NULL)

Answer (score 0):

In this query

```
(SELECT B.LOCID FROM DCCUMINVBASIC B WHERE A.MAPNAME='invdc4')
```

you are on table B and you are trying to make a condition over table A. This makes no sense.

Your query should look like this:

```
(SELECT B.LOCID FROM DCCUMINVBASIC B WHERE B.XXXX='yyyyy')
```

And it should return a single value (1 row and 1 column result).

Comment: I given Stockvalue location ID too (A.MAPNAME='invdc4' and a.location=10155000000024)

Answer (score 0):

In such cases its best to understand which rows are causing an issue here by providing multiple results.
To understand the rows causing an issue here, you should create a select statement first like :

```
SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM DCCUMINVBASIC B WHERE A.MAPNAME='invdc4') CNT FROM STOCKVALUE A;
```

In this case check for the rows with count greater than 1 and fix the select first before proceeding with the update statement.

Comment: OK but 4 location ID in DCCUMINVBASIC table i want update stock table in both table commonly match DOCID

Comment: Can you please provide the DDL of these two tables and a sample dataset ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to execute this query (also with `DISTINCT`):

```
SELECT B.LOCID FROM DCCUMINVBASIC B WHERE A.MAPNAME='invdc4'
```

and you will see what is the error.

Answer (score -1):

What the error code is complaining is that the query

> SELECT B.LOCID FROM DCCUMINVBASIC B WHERE A.MAPNAME='invdc4'

Is returning more than one rows and hence the outer query cannot execute as it needs a single value.

Comment: I USED DISTINCT BUT SAME ERROR

Comment: UPDATE STOCKVALUE A SET A.LOCATION=(SELECT DISTINCT B.LOCID FROM STOCKVALUE A,DCCUMINVBASIC B WHERE A.DOCID=B.DOCID AND A.MAPNAME='invdc4'AND A.MPLANT IS NULL)